# DXUTSetD3D11Device function missing from DXUT

Tags: windows, directx, direct3d, directx-11, dxut

I'm writing a basic program using direct3d and [DXUT](https://dxut.codeplex.com/).

I am creating a direct3d device manually with `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain()` and passing it to DXUT using the `DXUTSetD3D11Device()` function which, according to the documentation should be correct.

What confuses me is that I get an `LNK2019: unresolved external symbol` error when calling `DXUTSetD3D11Device()`. I can call other DXUT functions such as `DXUTCreateWindow()` just fine, also I have built DXUT myself and have linked to it properly.

When I look in DXUT.h I can find the declaration of `DXUTSetD3D11Device()` but when I look in DXUT.cpp I can't find any reference to this function, so I think this might be why I'm getting this linker error.

[This](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/30362.aspx) seems to be the same problem as mine.

I'll leave the relevant pieces of code here, just in case:

```
bool DXUTEngine::Initialise()
{
    HR(DXUTCreateWindow(m_appname));

    if(!m_pDirect3D->Initialise(DXUTGetHWND(), m_width, m_height))
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"\n\n Failed to initialise Direct3D\n\n");
        return false;
    }

    HR(DXUTSetD3D11Device(m_pDirect3D->GetDevice(), m_pDirect3D->GetSwapChain()));

    return true;
}
```

Here's where I create the device:

```
result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, driverType, NULL, 0, &featureLevel, 1,
D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_pSwapChain, &m_pDevice, NULL, &m_pContext);
```

At the moment I either think I'm doing something very wrong or that this function just doesn't exist. I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you post which point to MSDN forum, the DXUT11 framework was delivered in source code, so there is no lib files. so the error was not about any link errors.

Another important thing is: function DXUTSetD3D11Device **has no implementation** in DXUT framework. if you want to use it, you should implement it yourself.

Comment: First off all I actually built the code into the lib files myself so that's why I thought there could be a link error. Thanks for the answer anyway I just thought that it was strange that a seemingly important function wouldn't be implemented.

Comment: Also it would be great if you could give a source our reference for the function having no implementation. I'm just not sure why they would do that. Also maybe I'm misunderstanding what this function does?

Comment: Note this issue is covered by a thread on the [CodePlex](https://dxut.codeplex.com/discussions/531081) for DXUT11.